# Jobs in algorithm design

Tags: algorithms

I just wanted to know if there are actually jobs only devoted to creating and optimising algorithms after finishing a Bachelors degree. Or is it only restricted to PhD's?

I solve problems on SPOJ and CodeForces, but I'm not sure if I'd get a job doing something like that.

Comment: Starring this question because I'm interested in the answers as well, but I'm not even sure if this is in the scope of this site.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same too. But lets see.

Comment: I don't think that coding contests are representative of the idea of algorithms design you get in CS.

Comment: Sorry @Raphael if I've broken any rules or anything. But could you give me an idea of what would be representative of real algo design then. Thanks.

Comment: @ThorodanBrom It starts with stuff you learn from textbooks and goes on to the stuff published in academic channels.

Comment: You need domain knowledge to create and optimize algorithms. For example, how do you create algorithms for flight simulator without having aerodynamics knowledge?

Comment: I do agree you need domain knowledge, but one would usually have a domain expert in specialized cases as you've mentioned. The domain expert can break down the problem, but it's the computer scientist who is able to model it algorithmic-ally and efficiently.

Comment: Designing and optimizing algorithms is my job. I'm a research assistant, but I haven't finished a master's degree. So one option is to look for this type of jobs in academia. Typically though, you need to be doing your master thesis to be hired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be unusual to find an organisation advertising specifically for someone to design algorithms. Generally speaking a company will have a product or a number of products which go through an improvement and release cycle. Part of this will involve optimising algorithms/code. However to specialise so greatly I would have thought would mean such an employee would spend much of their time twiddling their thumbs! Any organisation nowadays generally wants someone to be multi-skilled (eg able to code as well)

Having said that, large organisations which engage in a lot of research (the likes of NASA, Google, Facebook, Bell Labs, Xerox of old) may have posts such as that. Bear in mind that those guys will be looking for real genius-level staff as well. (You may well be a genius.. :) )

I would try to broaden my horizons a little beyond just algos though, as after all, an algorithm is no good unless it can be implemented! And that will always bring its own set of challenges given available resources and the specific nature of the problem domain.

I know this isn't an "answer" just my thoughts. As a first port of call try typing "algorithm designer" into monster.com or similar job site! Good luck!

Comment: "I think it would be unusual to find an organisation advertising specifically for someone to design algorithms." -- I have seen such ads, rare as they may be. "I know this isn't an "answer" just my thoughts." -- then why post it as such?

Comment: Yes there are such jobs, I did a search after writing this. However as I suspected they generally also require coding and development skills. So to concentrate solely on the algorithms in isolation with no regard to their integration into a larger system *would* be unusual. My "answer" is too long for a comment. Feel free to -1 me.